# How to get data that is all within radius of somewhere, and within the radius I'm looking for?

Tags: postgresql, geolocation, postgis

I am using postgres and postgis.

I have Posts which have a `geometry`, with an attribute `visible_within_m` which is how many meters from that point the Post should be shown in results.

I can find Posts within some random radius of some random points by doing `ST_DWithin(geometry, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(a, b), 4326), 10000)`

However, I want to know how many Posts are **visible** with a radius of some random point.

How can I look up how many Posts are visible within a radius of some arbitrary point?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the distance between each point and the center of your circle. If the distance is grater than the radius then it is outside otherwise it's inside.

```
const EARTH_RADIUS     = 6371000;
const toRad            = function(num){return num*Math.PI/180};

var calculateDistance =
    function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){
        var dLat = toRad(lat2 - lat1);
        var dLon = toRad(lon2 - lon1);
        var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(toRad(lat1)) * 
                Math.cos(toRad(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        var distance = EARTH_RADIUS * 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        return distance;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a constant value for the distance, use the value stored in `visible_within_m`

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE ST_DWithin(geometry, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(a, b), 4326), visible_within_m);
```

On a side note, `st_dwithin` with geometries uses the distance unit of the projection, so for 4326 it is a (meaningless) distance in degrees, not in meters.

Comment: thanks.  so I just need to cast the type to geography?

Comment: yes, geography works with meters. Be careful to create the spatial index accordingly though (i.e. on `geometry::geography`)